# ActonCable not working on prod (Rails5 + Redis + Nginx + SSL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, redis, actioncable

In my app i have a ActionCable which is working fine locally, but cannot force it to work on production server.

My stack is:

- Rails 5.2
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Redis
- NGINX & Passenger

assets/javascripts/channels/index.coffee

```
App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer("/cable")
```

- cable.js

```
(function() {
  this.App || (this.App = {});

  App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer("/cable")

}).call(this);
```

- routes:

```
mount ActionCable.server => "/cable"
```

- config/environments/production.rb

```
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/*/, /https:\/\/*/]
```

- nginx sites-enabled/my-app

```
server{
        server_name subdomain.my-app.app;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    production;
        root         /home/deploy/my-app/current/public;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/iris.gemisoft.app/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/iris.gemisoft.app/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # REDIS / ACTIONCABLE
    location /cable {
      passenger_app_group_name subdomain_my-app_app_websocket;
      passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
     }
}


server {

   # if ($host = subdomain.my-app.app) {
   #     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   # } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

        server_name subdomain.my-app.app;
#return 404; # managed by Certbot                                
}


Expected behaviour: When Admin click a button, users gets a message.
Current behaviour (on prod): When admin clicks a button, nothing happens, in redis console i can see:

1559571365.936128 [1 127.0.0.1:53530] "publish" "test" "{\"message\":\"message\"}"
```

Update: cable.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

test:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

Comment: any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. In my setup i had both jquery_ujs and rails-ujs. Problem solved by removing jquery_ujs.